# Contact Form 7 Redirect in Thank you page By post ID or URL for Tracking Goal

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, contact-form-7

I want to redirect my contact Form 7 redirect to Thank you page by Post ID or Post URL. That's why I can track my Conversion Goal for an individual post.
For Extample: I have Project details page and here only one contact from. So it can redirect just one Thank you page. but I need thank you page for every single project and that may be used ID or URL.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to redirect contact form on thankyou page :

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
   window.location = 'www.pageurl?id=33';
}, false );
```

You need to put this code where you have added contact form. just create a single thankyou page, to identify page/post you can pass  id in the url parameter www.pageurl?id=33